# Simulating slower internet connection

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Throttle network bandwidth per application in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x)

I need to test my application on slower internet connection. Is there anyway to limit the connection speed. I tried to use Firefox throttle, but it does not work on newer versions of firefox. I am using OSX. Is there any way to limit bandwidth of the browser (chrome/firefox) for sometime.

Comment: You need to look at something to throttle your bandwidth. A search for "os x throttle bandwidth" turns up quite a few results but as I don't use Macs I cant comment on which is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can view more details in here - https://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox as it also mention about OSX:

> http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) if you only need to throttle HTTP/HTTPS traffic. Throtteling is only one of the many usefull features of this Software.

If you need to throttle all IP traffic you can use ipfw. [Here](http://weblog.bbzzdd.com/2010/11/16/throttling-bandwidth-in-mac-os-x/)'s a handy manual on how-to do this.

If you have [Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) installed (it's free from the Mac App store) you can use the "Network Link Conditioner". You can select from 11 built-in profiles for different network types such as 3G, Lossy Network, etc.