# Throttle network bandwidth per application in Mac OS X - 2016 version

Tags: macos, mac, throttling

I would like to ask this question again since it's passed a long time since the original post and many things have changed since then.
[Throttle network bandwidth per application in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x)

In my case I am using amazon cloud drive app on my macbook pro and when it's running pretty much I can't do anything else with the internet. Preferably I would like to be able to control the upload speed and download speed separately.